# Android eclipse: Unfortunately ProjectThing has stopped, error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I am new to android and have been creating a few simple apps recently, I decided to make a snap game but when I try and run it on the `AVD` I get this **error**: `Unfortunately ProjectThing has stopped`.

Main Code:

```
`package com.example.snapgame;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public TextView t1, t2, t3;
    public Button b1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        Snap();

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int score = 0;
                if(t1.equals(t2)){
                    score++;
                    t3.setText(score);
                }

            }
        });{

        }
    }

        private void Snap() {

            String aWords1[] = {"Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow"};
            String aWords2[] = {"Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow"};
            String randomColor1 = (aWords1[new Random().nextInt()]);
            String randomColor2 = (aWords2[new Random().nextInt()]);

            t1.setText(randomColor1);
            t2.setText(randomColor2);

        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}`
```

Main layout.XML:

```
`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="89dp"
        android:text="Snap!" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>`
```

Android Manifest.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.snapgame"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And logcat:

```
    11-24 10:36:25.967: D/AndroidRuntime(1153): Shutting down VM
11-24 10:36:25.967: W/dalvikvm(1153): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ad8b90)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153): Process: com.example.snapgame, PID: 1153
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.snapgame/com.example.snapgame.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=-689701214
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=-689701214
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at com.example.snapgame.MainActivity.Snap(MainActivity.java:47)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at com.example.snapgame.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-24 10:36:25.977: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     ... 11 more
11-24 10:36:28.937: I/Process(1153): Sending signal. PID: 1153 SIG: 9
11-24 10:39:08.297: D/AndroidRuntime(1201): Shutting down VM
11-24 10:39:08.297: W/dalvikvm(1201): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ad8b90)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201): Process: com.example.snapgame, PID: 1201
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.snapgame/com.example.snapgame.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=-1345881455
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=-1345881455
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at com.example.snapgame.MainActivity.Snap(MainActivity.java:47)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at com.example.snapgame.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-24 10:39:08.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     ... 11 more
11-24 10:39:10.557: I/Process(1201): Sending signal. PID: 1201 SIG: 9
11-24 10:39:52.907: D/AndroidRuntime(1248): Shutting down VM
11-24 10:39:52.907: W/dalvikvm(1248): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ad8b90)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248): Process: com.example.snapgame, PID: 1248
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.snapgame/com.example.snapgame.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=174154180
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=174154180
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at com.example.snapgame.MainActivity.Snap(MainActivity.java:47)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at com.example.snapgame.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-24 10:39:52.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1248):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, StackOverflow is not designed as a place to learn people to read StackTrace.

Answer (score 3):

First of all what is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ?

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal
>   index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the
>   size of the array.

If you check your logcat you'll see the line which throws this exception :

```
at com.example.snapgame.MainActivity.Snap(MainActivity.java:47)
```

So you have to look at the line 47 of your `MainActivity` java file.

---

How to solve this problem ?

It's here :

```
String randomColor1 = (aWords1[new Random().nextInt()]);
String randomColor2 = (aWords2[new Random().nextInt()]);
```

It should be

```
String randomColor1 = (aWords1[new Random().nextInt(aWords1.length)]);
String randomColor2 = (aWords2[new Random().nextInt(aWords2.length)]);
```

Why ?

Because `nextInt()` returns a pseudo-random uniformly distributed **int**. Or the possible values for an `int` is between `-2^31` and `2^31-1`.

Or the possible indexes for your arrays are from `0` to `yourArray.length - 1`.

Since the length of both arrays are from `0` to `3`, in your case, you will throw this exception when `nextInt()` returns an integer inferior than `0` or superior than `3`.

---

Fortunately, the API provided a method for you !

You have to use the overloaded method `nextInt(int n)` which returns a pseudo-random uniformly distributed `int` in the half-open range `[0, n)` (means 0 included and n **not** included).